# Sending and receiving data

Tags: php, actionscript-3

Not getting data back into flash from php that queries mysql data, think the problem is with my as3 code here?

The php works, the as3 posts to the php ok, its the returning of the variables to as3 that I am unsure about and seems to be the problem?

```
public static function MineData():void{


    var myRequest:URLRequest = new URLRequest("login.php");
    var myLoader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
    myLoader.dataFormat = URLLoaderDataFormat.VARIABLES;
    var myVariables:URLVariables = new URLVariables();


    myVariables.School_name_test = String(PostToPHP3.Temp_flash_TI_School_name_test);


    myRequest.method = URLRequestMethod.POST;
    myRequest.data = myVariables;


    function onLoaded(event:Event) {
        var myURLVariables:URLVariables = new URLVariables(event.target.data); 
        DT_display_string_teacher_login_teacher_first_name = myURLVariables.mined_teacher_first_name;

        Main.listeningFORPortalteacherlogin.tellMainPortalteacherlogin();
    }

    myLoader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onLoaded);
    myLoader.load(myRequest);
}
```

Kindest regards

Answer (score 0):

Within your PHP file, ensure you're only echoing back the values which should be returned to Flash. The format for this returned string is:

```
VarName=Value
```

With any further values appended to the same String using the & operator to separate them:

```
VarName=Value&VarName2=Value2
```

And so on. See the following example for how you might need to use it:

```
<?php
    echo "mined_teacher_first_name=" . $FIRST_NAME_RETURNED_FROM_SQL;
?>
```

This example obviously doesn't include all the PHP to retrieve the data from the database but that's how you get the data back to Flash. If you have a very large amount of data, you can also output an XML file from PHP and then parse that from within Flash.

I'll also add that your Flash code for extracting these values looks perfectly fine, although it's not absolutely necessary to convert them to a URLVariables object, you can in fact, access them directly from **event.data** if you so choose:

```
function onLoaded(event:Event) {
    DT_display_string_teacher_login_teacher_first_name = event.target.data.mined_teacher_first_name;

    Main.listeningFORPortalteacherlogin.tellMainPortalteacherlogin();
}
```

Comment: Thank you DJohnson, good to know someone else thinks my as3 is fine, and I will look again at the php side. I will post with the update after some experiments with the php code.

Comment: If you can't work it out, feel free to add your PHP code to the question so we can see where you might be going wrong.